# Trouble retreiving an entitiy from Google Cloud Datastore by Key in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I have an entity set up with a name identifier:

```
Namespace: [default]
Kind: Cocktail
Name: martini
```

I have a Google Cloud Function:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const projectId = 'my-project-name';
const datastore = Datastore({
  projectId: projectId
});

exports.getCocktail = (req, res) => {
  const key = datastore.key({path: ['Cocktail', 'martini']});
  debug = "Key = " + JSON.stringify(key);
  cocktail_result = datastore.get(key);
  message = JSON.stringify(cocktail_result);
  res.status(200).send(message + "\n"+debug);

  return;
};
```

The output I get:

```
{}
Key = {"name":"martini","kind":"Cocktail","path":["Cocktail","martini"]}
```

The `martini` entity in the Datastore isn't empty.

I've read through the documentation and tried quite a few variations, but I keep getting an empty object back.

Any obvious errors?

Comment: my-project-name is my actual project name in the real code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it's probably not the best way to do it, but I've stopped using Keys to retrieve and instead added a "name" property to the object which is the same as the key, and I use queries to retrieve:

```
const q = datastore.createQuery([j_kind]).filter('name', cocktail.toLowerCase());

datastore.runQuery(q, (err, entities) => {
  <snip> Do stuff here </snip>
});
```

And that works. I'd still like to know how to properly retreive using keys as I assume that's more efficient, but posting this answer for the benefit of anyone who stumbles through.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an entity you need to use the next syntaxis as in the example in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/2.0.x/DatastoreRequest):

```
const key = datastore.key(['Kind', keyId]);
```

The syntaxis:

```
const key = datastore.key({path['Kind', keyId]});
```

is used when you insert a new entity.

Comment: This another [example](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity) :

datastore.get(taskKey).then(results => {
  // Task found.
  const entity = results[0];

  console.log(entity);
});